# Reference/scope of object created in an Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope, response

I've been trying haplessly for hours so I thought I should ask (after scouring stackoverflow :S)

How do I access an object created in an ajax response:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "slideshow.xml", //xml file 
      dataType: "xml",
          success: function(xml) {
            var count = 0; //counter
              $(xml).find('site').each(function() {
                var url = $(this).find('url').text(); //url 
                var imageURL = $(this).find('imageURL').text(); 
                myArray[parseInt(count)] = new Array(imageURL, url);
                count++;
            });

            var slideshow = new simpleGallery({
                wrapperid: "topbar_scroller_inside",
                dimensions: [815, 264],
                imagearray: myArray,
        autoplay: [false, 30000, 99],
                persist: true,
                fadeduration: 1000
            }); 
    }});
```

The question is how do I access the 'slideshow' object created in the ajax success response?

I have tried accessing it for instance:

```
 <a id="prev" href="javascript:slideshow.navigate('prev')"></a>
```

however that failed.

I also tried it with:

```
  <a id="next" href="javascript:jQuery.proxy('slideshow', navigate('next'))"></a>
```

still failed, and not quite sure if $.proxy is the relevant function here.

Please, I could use your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Declare the variable above the ajax call.

`var slideshow;`

Then change the success function to use `slideshow = ...`.

Also, you should probably change the href of both of your `a` elements to be `#` and use jQuery bindings for the click functionality:

```
$('a#prev').click(function() {
    slideshow.navigate('prev');
    return false;
});
$('a#next').click(function() {
    slideshow.navigate('next');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, where do I bury my head. I can't believe it was something so simple. It had even tried declaring the variable above the ajax call, but my silliness, the variable was being declared twice, hence looked like it didn't work. Eeek... MANY thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Using JSON's json_decode(). It's pretty simple. It parses your js variables to php variables. Check it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: May I even know why that flag down?

Comment: The question was targeted to JavaScript/jQuery. You pointed to a PHP function. The answer seems to be totally unrelated to the question.